# ScrollView or its parent is useless

Tags: android, xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <ScrollView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

      <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical" >

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />

      </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

the titanium studio keeps on telling me that that ScrollView layout or its RelativeLayout parent is useless. What is wrong with my xml?

Comment: You should remove both the `ScrollView` and `LinearLayout` if you want `RelativeLayout` as your base layout.

Comment: Just change with my code...

Comment: Did you solve your question ?

Comment: Thanks man and please give me one upvote too..

Comment: i cant upvote, it says i need to have 15 reputations

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do it-

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >


      <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical" >

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />

      </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

Comment: @shijuB reason is same answer which match to me.

Comment: @shijuB Dear you have good points in few days that's mean you are good no doubt and i am not saying you copied me but our answer was same and i have given before your answer. and its not good way.

Answer (score 1):

Remove LinearLayout inside the ScrollView, as you only have one TextView. If you have more child than only just the TextView, you would have to take them inside LinearLayout under the ScrollView. Make your layout like below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<ScrollView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

           <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
 </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you are wrong dear. ScrollView only have one child only so you can't remove that child Linear else you can't add more view. Just problem was top View.

Comment: @ManishSrivastava And what if we do not want to make the whole layout scrollable and only the TextView? What would you advise then dear?

Comment: So yes you add Views above that scrollview but in that case error was only that because there is no use of Top Relative. That's it..

Comment: @ManishSrivastava I am glad your solution worked for him, but it is better to provide solution that is easily modifiable in the future too. And you cannot tell me that what I have provided is wrong. Did you try to check the layout I posted?

Comment: Ya I have already checked. but there is no difference between min and your code. and given same answer what is the benefit to others?

Comment: Dear do what you can do but you can't change truth. and believe in code and java, don't loss your energy in wrong way. don't give wrong knowledge to others. what you think you can only arrange people for negative vote and up vote? I have more than 2.5L visitors on my blog and if ones i post this on my blog i will get 100 upvote and you got same down vote. I think you understand it why I given you down vote.

Comment: And one more thing, I am not here for fighting with any one. Just i want help people. only that.